# How to change facebook apprequest "Accept" button into "Try Now"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When im sending apprequest trought my fb app (js) its sending apprequest with "Accept" button compare to other apps that display "Try Now" button..

I wonder how can I replace this button text into "Try Now"

Screenshot is attached[image]

Comment: I think it depends on the app type. For a canvas app, it’ll be “accept”, where as for mobile apps (iPad/android) it is “try now”.

Comment: Is it possible you already installed the last app, but not the other three?

Answer (score 1):

I had same question, and found what decide the button text. :)

It is decided by the fact that **the app which sent requests is listed in "Your Apps"**.
And you may already know, An app is listed in "Your Apps", when the user log in the app with facebook account.

I hope this might be helpful. :)

[image]